# Varios arquivos com HTML e PHP

Tags: php

Estou com um sistema de leitura de arquivos XML em andamento, escolhi a linguagem que não tenho tanta facilidade PHP, o fato e que não sei como pegar vários arquivos e alocar em uma variável, estou pegando apenas o endereço temporário do arquivos e faço a leitura, todo o processo que tem que ser feito e mostrado na tela já está funcionando porém unificado, so consigo fazer lendo apenas 1 arquivo por vocês e preciso ler vários arquivos por vez.

Alguém Sabe como ler muitos XML ?

Código de entrada:

```
<form action="teste2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="entXML" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="LER_ARQUIVO">
</form>
```

Tratamento com PHP

```
<?php

//Instanciando o OBJ
 $xml = new DOMdocument();

 //Pegando o TMP do FORM
 $arquivo = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'];

 //Carregando o XML
 $xml ->load($arquivo) or die("Erro ao carregar arquivo XML");



  //Entra dentro do NÓ pai do XML
  $arquivoXML = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );



//Navegando no Nodes(Nós)
  foreach( $arquivoXML as $xml){

          //Pega Nome
  $nomes = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "xNome" );
  $nome = $nomes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //Pega CNPJ
  $cnpjS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CNPJ" );
  $cnpj = $cnpjS->item(0)->nodeValue;

  //Mostra dados da Tabela EMIT
  echo "<b>Nome:</b> $nome"."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
  echo "<b>CNPJ:</b> $cnpj";

  echo"<br>";
  echo"<br>";
  echo"<br>";


  echo"-------------------------------VALORES----------------------------------";
  echo"<br>";
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------

  //Entra dentro do NODE "ide"
foreach( $arquivoXML as $xml){
        //Pega Numero da NF
          $nfs = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nNF" );
          $nf = $nfs->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //Pega Data de Emissão da NF
          $dataEMS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "dhEmi" );
          $dataEmi = $dataEMS->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //Pega CFOP
          $cfopS = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CFOP" );
          $cfop = $cfopS->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //Pega Valor do XML
          $vaPagS= $xml->getElementsByTagName( "vPag" );
          $vaPag = $vaPagS->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //Pega Status da Sefaz XML
          $motivoS= $xml->getElementsByTagName( "xMotivo" );
          $motivo = $motivoS->item(0)->nodeValue;

//Mostra Tabela na Tela
  echo "<table border=1;>";

      echo "<tr>";
          echo "<th>Nº NF</th>" ;
          echo "<th>Data Emissão</th>" ;
          echo "<th>CFOP</th>" ;
          echo "<th>Valor</th>" ;
          echo "<th>Status</th>" ;
      echo "</tr>";

      echo"<tr>";
          echo"<td>$nf</td>";
          echo"<td>$dataEmi</td>";
          echo"<td>$cfop</td>";
          echo"<td>$vaPag </td>";
          echo"<td>$motivo </td>";
      echo"</tr>";

  echo "</table>"; 
 }
}
```

[image: RESULTADO DE SAIDA]

Comment: Acho que o que voce precisa realmente é abrir múltiplos arquivos como um leitor de arquivos xml https://www.sobolsoft.com/howtouse/combine-xml-files.htm Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Não e isso, preciso trabalhar no meu codigo para que ele faça a leitura de multiplos XML, de todo modo Obrigado pela ajuda !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você precisa pegar multiplos arquivos, então você precisa tratar como um array.

Mude o `name` do input adicionando `[]` no final, desta forma:

```
<form action="teste2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="entXML[]" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="LER_ARQUIVO">
</form>
```

A partir de agora `entXML` é um array de arquivos e pode ser recuperado dessa forma:

```
 //Pegando o TMP do FORM
 $arquivos = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'];
```

ou por exemplo:

```
 $arquivo1 = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'][0];
 $arquivo2 = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'][1];
```

Neste [link](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.multiple.php) deve ficar mais claro.

---

Você pode tentar fazer um foreach em cima do `//Carregando o XML`, para cada posição de `$_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'];`, por exemplo:

```
foreach($arquivos as $arquivo) {
    //Carregando o XML
    $xml ->load($arquivo) or die("Erro ao carregar arquivo XML");
    ...
```

Comment: Certo já arrumei essa parte e já configurei tbm o php.ini agora consigo pegar ate 1000 endereços dos arquivos XML, porém não consigo entrar dentro de todos esses XML e pegar os NodesValue que preciso, estou pegando manualmente os valores com foreach e pegano os endereço usando o for loop mas e pra fazer a leitura desses varios caminhos qual loop ultilizo ? isso que não estou conseguindo !

Comment: <?php
//Instanciando o OBJ
$xml = new DOMdocument();
$caminho = $_FILES['entXML']['tmp_name'];
for( $i = 0; $i < count($caminho);$i++){  
      $xml ->load($caminho[$i]) or die("Erro ao carregar arquivo XML");      
      $arquivoXML = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );
        //PRECISO FAZER ISSO ESSE FOREACH RODAR EM 
        //TODOS OS ARQUIVOS XML 
        foreach( $arquivoXML as $xml){
          $nomes = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "xNome" );
          $nome = $nomes->item(0)->nodeValue;
          echo "<b>Nome:</b> $nome"."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
 }
}

Comment: editei a minha resposta, ve se deu para entender?

Comment: Bom Dia, no caso então seriam 2 forEach um pro carregamento do load que nesse caso ele vai carregar dos os XML nas suas respectivas posições e outra pra carregar os dados dos NODES e isso ? Tou tentando implementar esse código aqui

Comment: Isso, um foreach acima pra ler cada xml que voce fez upload

Comment: <?php
$xml = new DOMdocument();

  $arquivo = $_FILES['caminho']['tmp_name'];   

   for( $i = 0; $i < count($arquivo);$i++){

 
     foreach ($arquivo as $arquivo[$i]) {

      //Abrindo o Obj para leitura dos NODES(Nós)
   $xml ->load($arquivo[$i]) or die("Erro ao carregar arquivo XML");
   
     //Entra dentro da Tabela "Emit"
     $arquivoXML = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "nfeProc" );

     //Pega Nome
    $nomes = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "xNome" );
    $nome = $nomes->item(0)->nodeValue;

     echo "<b>Nome:</b><b> $nome </b>"."<br>";
     }
   }

Comment: Desse jeito que citei acima ele funciona porém duplica os valores, por exemplo se eu selecionar dois XMLs ele mostra 2x mais o campos que eu quero que imprima na tela